# I just fresh installed Void linux but I am stuck in login screen unable to login?

Tags: login, distributions, void-linux

I just fresh installed Void linux but I am stuck in login screen unable to login through the GUI. Doesn't matter how many times I type in correct password it still returns me to login screen.

I have opened the console (Ctrl + Alt + F2) where I was able to login as root. I changed the user account's password but again when I reboot I wasn't able to log in with changed password.

I can successfully login as this new user account at the console login.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks for your answers and advice.

Running the command `grep '^void:' /etc/passwd` as asked for in the comments gave me,

```
void:x:1000:1000:Void User:/home/void:/bin/bash
```

Running the command `usermod -s /bin/bash void` gave me `no changes`

[image: grep '^void:' /etc/passwd command]

[image: void: /etc/passwd command]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135328/discussion-on-question-by-leviathan-i-just-fresh-installed-void-linux-but-i-am-s).